# What is the difference between 'which' and 'that'?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between

> A Random Variable is a variable **which** represents the outcome of a random experiment.

and

> A Random Variable is a variable **that** represents the outcome of a random experiment.

?

Comment: In **those** two sentences, there is no difference. The restrictive relative clause _that/which represents the outcome of a random experiment_ has its relative pronoun as subject (so it must be present, and can't be deleted as usual, because subject NPs are required in English), and that relative pronoun may be **either** _that_ or _which_, since the relative clause is restrictive. If the relative clause were non-restrictive, like the one in _a random variable, which is a term referring to a non-constant memory location,_  then _which_ would be required, and _that_ would be ungrammatical.

Comment: It's a free choice in integrated relatives like your example. They show no semantic difference and no syntactic difference other than what follows from "that" not being relative pronoun, but a subordinator.

Comment: Broadly, it hardly matters but to anyone who cares, "that" defines and "which" explains.

Prove this simply by comparing "that which" to "which that"… 

Is either of those aceptable? Then, why?